# how to get specific rows at the top after performing sorting in tabulator javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, tabulator

I am trying to get the rows of a table at the top after performing sorting using a tabulator. Is there any inbuilt functionality in the tabulator to achieve this?

Example:

actual table:

Sno        Animal            City

1          Dog               Boston

2          Cat               Chicago

3          Rat               Texas

4          Eagle             Colorado

Return table:

I need to get Cat at the Rat after sorting based on Animal

Sno        Animal            City

3          Rat               Texas

2          Cat               Chicago

1          Dog               Boston

4          Eagle             Colorado

Comment: First need to sort on Animal alphabetically ascending, and then get specific row RAT at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to achieve this. You could either use a custom sorter function that ensures they are moved to the top of the table:

```js
{title:"Name", field:"name", sorter:function(a, b, aRow, bRow, column, dir, sorterParams){
        //a, b - the two values being compared
        //aRow, bRow - the row components for the values being compared (useful if you need to access additional fields in the row data for the sort)
        //column - the column component for the column being sorted
        //dir - the direction of the sort ("asc" or "desc")
        //sorterParams - sorterParams object from column definition array

        // logic to normally sort rows an ensure row is on the top.

        return a - b;
    },
}
```

Details of how to build a custom sorter can be found in the [Sorting Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/sort)

or you could use a combination of the ***dataSorted*** callback and the ***moveRow***

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    dataSorted:function(sorters, rows){
        //sorters - array of the sorters currently applied
        //rows - array of row components in their new order

        var rowID = 2 the id for the row you want to move
        table.moveRow(2, table.getRows()[0], true); //move the row with an id of 2 and insert it at the top of the table
    },
});
```

Details on how to move rows can be found in the {Movable Rows Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/move#example-table-movable-rows)